# Binding and x:Bind, one is working

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, xbind

I`m doing some tests with Bindings and x:Bind and I found out some interesting thing.

XAML

```
<ListView Background="White" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrenciesViewModel.Currencies.Currencies}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Currency">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Ok so first x:Bind is to viewModel which have property CurrenciesViewModel (model name CurrencyListViewModel) which have property Currencies (model name CurrencyList) which have property Currencies and it is  ObservableColletion

So this is working when I`m adding object like this

```
CurrenciesViewModel.Currencies.Currencies.Add(new Currency() { Name = "test" });
CurrenciesViewModel.Currencies.Currencies.Add(new Currency() { Name = "test2" });
```

But when I`m downloading my models by my DataProvider (simple rest with xml) with one method

```
Task<CurrencyList> GetCurrencyList();
```

So my first property CurrencyViewModel in my main ViewModel is like this

```
CurrenciesViewModel = new CurrencyListViewModel(await DataProvider.GetCurrencyList());
```

Then my listView is empty! I checked if my data is downloaded and yes it is...
I changed x:Bind with Binding and everything is working.

I can copy-paste all classes if you want guys. But please tell me wtf ;)

Comment: My first assumption was that the binding gets broken because you're creating a new CurrencyListViewModel. But since it's working with Binding, and not with x:Bind, my second guess would be that you're missing Mode=OneWay on x:Bind? The default is OneTime.

Comment: @igrali: I think the same: `Mode=OneWay` is missing in the binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how the default binding works in {x:Bind} vs {Binding}. In {x:Bind} the default binding is OneTime, but in {binding} the default Binding is OneWay. So even when you update the viewmodel the data will not change by default in x:binding.

```
To Resolve Change 
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
To:
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind Name Mode=OneWay} "/>
```